# Using backref in ElegantBook.sty: Incompatible backref package

Tags: biblatex, natbib, backref

I am using `elegantbook.sty` to write a book.

The `elegantbook.sty` is using `biblatex` which is not compatible with `backref`.

Anyone knows and could help with how to enable using `beackref` or similar functionality in `elegantbook.sty`? I was trying to change `biblatex` to `natbib` in `elegantbook.sty` source file, but that produced many errors on things that colided with rest of the `elegantbook.sty`.

This is the last bit missing in my book, so help would be much appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper,citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=numeric,color=blue]{elegantbook}

\addbibresource[location=local]{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent Lorem ipsum...

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=\ebibname]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` has a `backref` option, which you can set to `true`, just like you set other `biblatex` options.

Comment: Many thanks! It indeed works when I add `backref=true` as an option to `\RequirePackage[backend=\ELEGANT@bibend,citestyle=\ELEGANT@citestyle,  bibstyle=\ELEGANT@bibstyle,backref=true]{biblatex}` in `elegantbook.sty`. Could you help me with how I can pass this option without modifying the `elegantbook.sty`? I tried `\PassOptionsToPackage{backref=true}{biblatex}` before and after `\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{elegantbook}` and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know `elegantbook` and can't seem to find it in TeX Live. But you could probably set this with `biblatex`'s `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`.

Comment: Yes, I confirm it works: adding `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=true}` just after `\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{elegantbook}` solves my problem. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `elegantbook.cls` here (it seems to be on CTAN, but only on MiKTeX, don't know why, given the license is LPPL), so I can't test it. But the class seems to load `biblatex` and the `backref` package is documented to be incompatible with it.  However, `biblatex` itself provides comparable functionality, which can be enabled with the `backref` option. Since the class already loads the package, you can set it in your preamble with:

```tex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=true}
```

Comment: It is fully solved now - many thanks again!